# iOS Auto-resize custom cell width in UITableViewHeaderFooterView.ContentView Subview

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, uitableviewsectionheader

I create a custom cell `PVIssueTypeSectionHeaderCell` and add it as a subview for `ContentView` in the header view with this code:

```
public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    var cell = (PVIssueTypeSectionHeaderCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(HeaderCellKey);
    if(cell == null)
    {
        cell = PVIssueTypeSectionHeaderCell.Create();
    }

    cell.ViewModel = this.GroupedIssueTypesFilter.ElementAt((int)section);

    var headerView = tableView.DequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(HeaderFooterViewKey);

    if (headerView == null)
    {
        headerView = new UITableViewHeaderFooterView(HeaderFooterViewKey);
    }

    headerView.ContentView.AddSubview(cell);

    return headerView;
}
```

But the custom cell's width does not auto-resize as you could see in these images below.

**This is in iPad Landscape mode and in iPhone Portrait mode:**

[image: ipad landscape/iphone portrait]

**While this one is in iPad Portrait mode:**

[image: ipad portrait mode]

How to make the custom cell automatically resize its width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally make it work by returning my custom cell's `ContentView` directly in `GetViewForHeader`.

```
public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    var cell = (PVIssueTypeSectionHeaderCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(HeaderCellKey);
    if(cell == null)
    {
        cell = PVIssueTypeSectionHeaderCell.Create();
    }

    cell.ViewModel = this.GroupedIssueTypesFilter.ElementAt((int)section);

    return cell.ContentView;
}
```